# Error calling member function when session expires (middleware)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

When my session expires and reload the page I get the following error (line signaled in the following code block):

> Error: Call to a member function `hasRole()` on `null`

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if ($request->user()->hasRole('admin')) // this line
            return $next( $request );
        else
            abort( 401, 'Esta acción no está autorizada.' );
    }
}
```

`hasRole()` is a function in my `User` model that checks if the user has the permissions to access some admin routes:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     *  Role-user relation (one-to-many)
     */
    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Role::class )->withTimestamps();
    }


    /**
     *  Authorize roles
     */
    public function authorizeRoles($roles) {
        if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles))
            return true;

        abort( 401, 'Esta acción no está autorizada.' );
    }


    /**
     *  Check if user has specified role
     */
    public function hasRole($role) {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$request->user()` only contains the authenticated user object if the session actually exists. If the session expired like you described, this will return null. You have to consider this, when you're using it:

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::check() && $request->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(401, 'Esta acción no está autorizada.');
    }
}
```